# Design Custom Edit text in android

Tags: android, edit

I need to desgin a Edit Text like the below image. Please suggest some inputs![image]

thanks

Comment: http://alinberce.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/android-edittext-with-custom-font-and-clear-button/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_sam"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textfield"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Reference No(Optional)" >

    </TextView>

     <EditText
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textfield"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:hint="12345" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and background drawable is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#00000000" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#a1a1a1" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="3dip"
        android:bottomRightRadius="3dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="3dip"
        android:topRightRadius="3dip" />

</shape>
```

This will look like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At its simplest form you will have to **write your constructors corresponding to all the constructors of the base class**. For example if you are going to extend TextView to create a DateView then following three constructors will be created for DateView class:

```
public class DateView extends TextView {
   public DateView(Context context) {
      super(context);
      //--- Additional custom code --
   }

   public DateView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      //--- Additional custom code --
   }

   public DateView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
      //--- Additional custom code --
   }
}
```

By the same way you can also define **your constructor** and put all styling stuff in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Extend a relative layout putting a TextView and an EditText in their correct posistions

Answer (score 0):

You can add a TextView and EditText in LinearLayout Horizontally.
You will need to create a custom Shape Drawable resource and add it as background for that parent Linear Layout. You can give textStyle BOLD to textview and textStyle NORMAL to edittext.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming:

- 'Reference number (optional)' is your placeholder
- '1234567890' is the value being edited.

If this is correct, you have to do following:

- Override `draw` method of `TextField` and their first draw the placeholder set and then call `super.draw()`
- Set required left padding, so that text being edited will not overwrite the place holder.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple just create an image in paint.. add text to the image i.e write "reference number option". save it then copy that into your res>drawable folder . Android drawable left will do it...

your xml is like

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNUmber"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColorHint="#cccccc" >

    <requestFocus />
```